# Defining a new command to declare a function in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to plot continuous, piece-wise linear functions in tikz using `declare function`. I can build the functions by hand, but I'd like to define a new command to make this easier. The parameters of the new command should be the y-values of the function at x=0, 1, and 2.

Here is my attempt, followed by the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\newcommand{\build}[3]{declare function={f(\x)=(\x<=1)*((#2-#1)*\x+#1)+and(\x>1,\x<=2)*((#3-#2)*(\x-1)+#2);}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=(\x<=1)*(2*\x)+ and(\x>1,\x<=2)*(-2*\x+4);}]
    \begin{axis}[samples at={0,1,2}, ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={1,2}, xmin=0, xmax=2, xtick={1,2}]
        \addplot{f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[\build{0}{2}{0}]
    \begin{axis}[samples at={0,1,2}, ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={1,2}, xmin=0, xmax=2, xtick={1,2}]
        \addplot{f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first piece-wise function is built by hand, and the second is my attempt to plot the same function using the new command `build`. My grasp of the subtleties of `newcommand` is weak, and a few searches haven't led me to an obvious error. How can I fix my new command `build` to achieve my desired effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to convert your macro into a style. Or define a function of several arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\tikzset{build/.style n args={3}{declare
function={f(\x)=(\x<=1)*((#2-#1)*\x+#1)+and(\x>1,\x<=2)*((#3-#2)*(\x-1)+#2);}}}
\tikzset{declare function={mypiecewise(\x,\a,\b,\c)=(\x<=1)*((\b-\a)*\x+\a)+and(\x>1,\x<=2)*((\c-\b)*(\x-1)+\b);}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=(\x<=1)*(2*\x)+ and(\x>1,\x<=2)*(-2*\x+4);}]
    \begin{axis}[samples at={0,1,2}, ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={1,2}, xmin=0, xmax=2, xtick={1,2}]
        \addplot{f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[build={0}{2}{0}]
    \begin{axis}[samples at={0,1,2}, ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={1,2}, xmin=0, xmax=2, xtick={1,2}]
        \addplot{f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[samples at={0,1,2}, ymin=0, ymax=2, ytick={1,2}, xmin=0, xmax=2, xtick={1,2}]
        \addplot{mypiecewise(x,0,2,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]