# \tikzpicture vs. axis vs. \pgfmathdeclarefunction vs. \tikzmath vs. \tikzset vs. \def\func

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, function

we can declare a function in the [`tikzpicture` options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35191/222785), in \axis option, [in `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, in `\tikzmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235006/declaring-sinc-in-tikz), by using [`\tikzset`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575721/defining-a-new-command-to-declare-a-function-in-tikz), by using the [`\def\func`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35195/222785), etc... That is confusing as hell (at least, for a newbie). What is the difference between these forms of function declaration?

Comment: `\def` is just tex so for tikz it's as if it were not there and you have just typed its definition directly, `\tikzset`  can always be used as an alternative to the options to set any tikz setting not just functions, so really the only surprising thing is the `\pgfmath` form. but the keyval options have to have some underlying command that they invoke. The whole point of tikz  is to add a higher syntax layer over pgf functionality so the fact that there is a tikz and a pgf syntax shouldn't be that surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way of defining a PGFMath function is [`\pgfmathdeclarefunction`](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#%5Cpgfmathdeclarefunction).

The [`/pgf/declare function` key](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#pgf/declare:function) is also provided by PGFMath and is simply usable with TikZ/`\tikzset` and PGFPlots/`\pgfplotsset` (as they automatically search in the `/pgf` namespace as well).
It is just a frontend to `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` where you can use control sequences instead of arguments `#1`, `#2`, ….

The [TikZMath `function`](https://tikz.dev/library-math#sec-58.6) is yet another frontend to `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` which just puts the body of the function inside a `\tikzmath` statement inside the body of `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. (It also deals with arguments the same as `/pgf/declare function`.)

The `\def\func` thing isn't a PGFMath function but just a macro that expands to something else. In the context of the link question, a point is made that a macro `\func` works independent from its context as long as its expansion is understood as well. With TikZ and PGFPlots, [GNUPlot](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.6) can be used to evaluate a function, however, it will not understand PGFMath functions per se. (And TikZ will not transform a PGFMath expression to an expression understood by GNUPlot.)